# DNS Server gone and now I get Zone Not Loaded by DNS Server

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

We have several domains in our infrastructure, separated by differing subnets (obviously).  From our primary domain (call it domain A), we have a DNS forward lookup zone to domain B (which consists of two virtual DC servers, no workstations).  We'll call them DC1 and DC2.  I was tasked with decommissioning DC1 in the remote domain.  I attempted to demote it, but it told me beforehand that it was the last DNS server in the domain (it wasn't), so before I demoted it I removed the DNS role (2012 R2).  It then let me demote it, and everything seemed ok.

Today I learned that the DNS servers in our primary domain can't resolve the remote domain because "Zone not loaded by DNS Server".  The primary server in the SOA record is DC1, and I can't change it because it is grey out.  DC2 is still an active DNS server, but its probably not the "master" DNS server because of how I went about this.

What is the method to straighten out this forward lookup zone so that I have DC2 as the primary server in the SOA?  I thought about deleting the forward lookup zone on domain A side and reinstalling it, but I'm not sure everything is correct on domain B side to allow that to happen.

Comment: `we have a DNS forward lookup zone to domain B` - I don't understand that statement. Do you mean that you have conditional forwarders from domainA to domainB? It also sounds like the DNS zone in domainB was not AD integrated and that DC1 was the primary DNS server and DC2 was the secondary DNS server for the zone in question. If that's the case, then the zone is in a text file at `C:\Windows\System32\dns`. You should be able to simply delete the DNS zone on DC2 and recreate it as a standard/primary zone on DC2 using the text file as the source for the zone.

Comment: Rather than setting DC2 as the primary server in SOA, could you change DC2 to be DC1, or at least so that it listens for DNS requests as if it's DC1?  I suspect it might be easier if there are no drawbacks to doing that.